# Expanding the div beyond screen size

Tags: html, css

my problem is specific to the background image. I have applied a background image to the body and centred it horizontally. For each page I will add a paragraph below the header and each one will be a different size causing scroll. The background image must flow behind the paragraph but I can't make the body tag to expand to include the paragraph, meaning the background image cuts off when you scroll down. I don't want to set a specific height because that will make the page scroll beyond the paragraph. I've tried just about every combination of position relative/absolute and height/min-height I can think of.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="paragraph">
            <p>text!</p>
        </div
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    background:             url('/images/bg.png');
    margin:                 0;
    padding:                0;
    height:                 100%;
    min-height:             100%;
}

body {
    margin:                 0;
    padding:                0 0 50px 0;
    background-image:       url('../images/fullheader.gif');
    background-position:    center 20px;
    background-repeat:      no-repeat;
    position:               absolute;
    top:                    0px;
    bottom:                 0px;
    right:                  0px;
    left:                   0px;
    min-height:             100%;
}

.paragraph {
    width:                  640px;
    padding:                10px 20px;
    margin:                 400px auto 0 auto;
    min-height:             100%;
}
```

I can post a screen shot if that helps.

Comment: Please create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your problem.

Comment: show me a fiddle or screen shot?

Comment: why not you try full page background image here is a refrence http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: I don't know how to use jsfiddle but here are some screenshots. [screenshot 1](http://laufofbread.co.uk/images/fullpage.png) [screenshot 2](http://laufofbread.co.uk/images/fullpagescroll.png)

Comment: Use my fiddle. just click on the link stated at my answer

Comment: At least post a link to a live example. Otherwise it's not very likely anybody can help.

Answer (score 0):

add css to body like this

```
       body {
             background:#fff url(background.jpg) repeat-y top center;
             margin:0px;
             padding:0px;
            }
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have added that vertical repeat isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

If vertical repeat is not an option and your bg image of course cannot be endless, I think the only way to not cut off the image after some scrolling is fixing it's position:

```
body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

No, there might be another solution, but in most cases this won't look very well: Set the `background-size`, e.g.:

```
body {
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: That makes the background image disappear when you scroll down, but thanks. I really need a way to either make the overflow visible or expand the div to include the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is keeping the background with height enough to cover the size of your paragraphs and with the restriction of **not repeat**  and **not distort the aspect radio** there is a simple and clean solution
Locate the background in the body tag .
Set its size to auto for horizontal size and 100% for the height
The paragraph, as being contained by the body will push the body height and this will push your background height without distortion of the aspect ratio

```
body {
    width:100%; <!-- or what ever.....-->
    background:url("whatever.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size:auto 100%;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/6Nedb/) for you. i used a wikipedia image. Play with it modifying the amount of paragraphs, etc... Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, the problem with this is it dramatically resizes the image so it doesn't go outside of the screen size anyway but I'm playing around with it now to see if you can see the overflow when it is larger.